# android firestore adds up date on top of duplicate data

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

[image: firestore dataset]

As you can see in the image, whenever I try to update(not replace) a field with a new value, it duplicates the data, and adds up on top of the duplicate. What is causing this issue?

Whenever a user posts, I need to add the post id to an existing array of post ids.

hierarchy:

users - collection - document(emblem(String), photo(String), postIds(String[])...)

```
mDb = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        // remove old ids
        Map<String, Object> oldIds = new HashMap<>();
        oldIds.put("posts", _oldPostList);

        // add new ids
        Map<String, Object> newIds = new HashMap<>();
        _oldPostList.add(_newValue);
        newIds.put("posts", _oldPostList);

        String docId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail();

        DocumentReference docRef = mDb.collection("users").document(docId);

        docRef.update("posts", FieldValue.arrayRemove(oldIds)).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                docRef.update("posts", FieldValue.arrayUnion(newIds)).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                        sendBroadcast(_context, _action, true, null);
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        sendBroadcast(_context, _action, false, null);
                    }
                });
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                sendBroadcast(_context, _action, false, null);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the structure you want is a list of posts, not a list of maps of lists of posts. If that is the case, the problem is that you are supplying the "posts" key twice - once in the update call and again in the data (Map) you pass. Instead of putting the post list into a map and passing the map like this

```java
// Don't do this - creates a list of maps, not a list of posts
Map<String, Object> oldIds = new HashMap<>();
oldIds.put("posts", _oldPostList);
docRef.update("posts", FieldValue.arrayRemove(oldIds));
```

you should just pass the list directly, since the update call already defines the "posts" key.

If you just want to add a new post to the list, you don't need to remove the old list first either. You can just use [`arrayUnion`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array) to add the new post to the existing list like this:

```java
docRef.update("posts", FieldValue.arrayUnion(_newValue));
```

Take a look at the [Firestore docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array) for some more examples too.